# Why DataSourceTransactionManage does not roll back while HibernateTransactionManager does?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

While building an app using spring and hibernate , if I use `DataSourceTransactionManager`, then on exception , it does not roll back. Seems like it uses auto-comit in different session. However , if I change the transaction manager to `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager`, the roll back works as expected. 
Or is it that if we use hibernate , then we need to use `HibernateTransactionManager`?

N.b: My service  annotated with  `@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Throwable.class} )`

Comment: What is the underlying database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with plain hibernate the following is needed to manage transactions

```
Session s = sessionfactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
tx = s.beginTransaction();
// Your data manipulation here
tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
if (tx != null) { tx.rollback();}
} finally {
s.close();
}
```

This is also what the `HibernateTransactionManager` does (open a session if needed, start transaction, afterwards commit/rollback).

Now what you are trying to do is the following (which is kind-of similair to the `DataSourceTransactionManager`, that operates on the `DataSource  instead of the session.)

```
Session s = sessionfactory.openSession();
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = s.connection();
    // Your data manipulation here
    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (conn != null) { 
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        catch (IOExceptin) {}
    }
} finally {
    s.close();
}
```

Which isn't going to work as the actual transactional unit, the session, is never getting informed of the commit or rollback. So in the worst case, depending in your flush-mode, everything (or partially) gets committed.

In short **always use the transaction manager which fits your technology.**

When using plain hibernate use the `HibernateTransactionManager`, when using JPA use the `JpaTransactionManager`, don't use the `DataSourceTransactionManager` in those cases as that is usable only in situations where **only** plain JDBC is used.

The [`DataSourceTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) clearly states that it operates on the DataSource and underlying connection. Whereas when one uses Hibernate the transaction is controlled by the hibernate `Session`, this is the level where the [`HibernateTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html) operates on. For JPA this is the `EntityManager` and this is what the [`JpaTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) recognizes.

Comment: Can you post a link which says that DataSourceTransactionManager is only for plain JDBC.

Comment: There isn't any (the javadocs do some hints in that direction), but it  simply is the way it is. The `DataSourceTransactionManager` knows nothing of the hibernate `session` and will never trigger a flush or commit on it. Hence nothing will happen. It will call commit on the connection but as no sql has been issued nothing will be committed (unless you call flush throughout all your DAOs methods).

Comment: 'nothing will be committed'- that is not true (and yes without explicit flush). Data gets saved. Problem is with roll back.

Comment: Then you have some manual tx management else nothing would be committed. BUt as stated you simply have to use the appropriate tx manager for the technology else it will not work. You aren't going to use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` and expect it to roll JMS messages....

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html):

> PlatformTransactionManager implementations normally require knowledge
>   of the environment in which they work: JDBC, JTA, Hibernate, and so
>   on.
>
> If you use JTA in a Java EE container then you use a container
>   DataSource, obtained through JNDI, in conjunction with Spring’s
>   JtaTransactionManager.
>
> You can also use Hibernate local transactions easily...
>
> In this case, you need to define a Hibernate LocalSessionFactoryBean,
>   which your application code will use to obtain Hibernate Session
>   instances ... in this case is of the HibernateTransactionManager type.
>
> In the same way as the DataSourceTransactionManager needs a reference
>   to the DataSource, the HibernateTransactionManager needs a reference
>   to the SessionFactory.

Although:

> DataSourceTransactionManager will binds a JDBC Connection from the
>   specified DataSource to the current thread, potentially allowing for
>   one thread-bound Connection per DataSource.

the Session won't be bound to the current transaction and you need both for local transactions.

This is what hibernate or JPA specific TM would do for you. They will associate the persistence context and one connection per transaction per thread.

If you choose JTA transactions than an external TM will coordinate transactions. DB connections will be released aggressively after each statement, which is fine as long as the external TM will always return the same connection to the same thread during a global transaction life.